# Typescript: Deeply mapping keys and types for complex dynamic scenarios

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is a bit hard to explain so I will start with what I WANT to accomplish and try to explain the question as best I can:

Note: I don't care which version of typescript is involved: any solution would be great.

```
interface Type {}
interface ExtendedType1 extends Type {}
interface ExtendedType2 extends Type {}
interface Type2 {}

type Lookup<T> = { [key: number]: T } | { [key: string]: T };

// This monster part is giving me trouble 
// and has a type error I can't find a good way around.
export type DeepKeyMap<TLookupValue, TLookup extends TLookupValue | Record<string, TLookupValue>, TMappedValue> =
  | TLookup extends TLookupValue ? TMappedValue : { [key in keyof TLookup]: DeepKeyMap<TLookupValue, TLookup[keyof TLookup], TMappedValue> };

interface ITest<TType extends Lookup<Type[]>> {
  data: TType;
}

class Test<TType extends Lookup<Type[]>, TOther extends DeepKeyMap<Type[], TType, Type2>> {
  source: ITest<TType>;
  mapped: TOther;

  constructor(options: ITest<TType>) {}
}

const t = new Test({
  data: {
    test: {
      check: [{} as ExtendedType1]
    },
    test2: {
      check2: [{} as ExtendedType2]
    }
  }
});

t.mapped.test.check; // <- Should be Type2
```

Essentially, I am trying to figure out a deep mapping of types where an input object will determine the keys of another object using as much inference as possible. So in my example the big mysterious part for me is the `DeepMap<Lookup<T>, MappedType>` type.

I've been through a large amount of googling for nigh similar examples, but none match up for deeply nested keys.

So finally hitting my: time to ask end of the wire :) Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: Consolidated and fixed example to the current progress of what I've come up with so far.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what you're asking for and the code does not constitute a [mcve].  Note that [empty classes and types make for poor examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) because the type system is structural.  You use `IMyClass` without the required type parameter.  The type `InstanceProvider` is not defined.  Et cetera.  Please consider updating the code to be a demonstrable example; ideally something that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play).  Good luck!

Comment: Is [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHAptA3tALtAvNARLPtAL4CwAUKJDAKIAemyAdgCbKsIoCM0yjLVjC6oMyTLzz5i5KuCjQGTNhxEAmPgLbCkovpg1SZlAJbMmAJwBmYYKnXosutQC5ozAK4BbAEbILANyklJi60AAiyMiIALJgiAA8sAA00ADKqeEAfLiOANoA0tBm0ADWyPAA9lZwALpusIW1mspC6dAA-BHQbpHRcYmNBbWpGRE5spTUCjHwAMLyEEktgjCVPgBWyMCYOWiU0NBe8SisAIS9UbHxSakieSNwzllBAPSv0FUeAOSs0H6YSzFLyIEDILwsbCYAAWJggB2gwEqzAgmAsHh2lQsAApKohMCZkRA3BhWGBMGAGqQAJSOWSTKhEqHIVG5ZjIADu0FmCxo2P2FEOZIpJIRhyYqNFgsOMuA0O2pTceXZXKUglUum42OptTFpGSeolBilMtl8uAiugys5ii07E4zm1uulh1krsoJGpAUoIRZmAAdMdEKd-Ub-XKFW9XuogA) what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed up my example: and I'm looking through your example you posted. So far I think it's exactly what I needed! I'll get back to here and let you know if it's the answer in a moment.

Comment: Yup your solution solved it perfectly for me. If you post as an answer I'll flag it as such :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `DeepMap` to be something that recursively walks down through the properties in a type `T`, replacing any properties of some source type `S` to some destination type `D`.  If so, then one might define it like this:

```
type DeepMap<T, S, D> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends S ? D : DeepMap<T[K], S, D> }
```

Let's test it, but we need to add some properties to your example types so that they are structurally distinct.  [All empty types are considered equivalent to each other](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), which could lead to surprising results.

```
class Type { t = "T" }
class ExtendedType1 extends Type { et1 = "" }
class ExtendedType2 extends Type { et2 = "" }
interface Type2 { type2: number; }
```

So, then `MyClass`'s constructor should take an `options` parameter of type `{data: T}` for some generic `T`, and I guess the `mapped` property should be of type `DeepMap<T, Type[], Type2>`:

```
class MyClass<T extends object> {
  mapped!: DeepMap<T, Type[], Type2>; // you'd better implement this
  constructor(options: { data: T }) { }
}
```

Note that `mapped` is not actually initialized to anything, so at runtime this will not behave as desired... but I assume you'll deal with that.  Finally we can see if `test`'s type is what you want to see:

```
const test = new MyClass({
  data: {
    test: {
      check: [new ExtendedType1()]
    },
    test2: {
      check: [new ExtendedType2()]
    }
  }
});

test.mapped.test.check; //Type2
```

Looks good.  Of course there might be all kinds of edge cases where `DeepMap` as defined above doesn't do what you want (e.g., what do you want to see when `T` has union-typed properties where one of the union elements is assignable to `S`?  What do you want to see if `T` has function-valued properties where one of its arguments or return type are assignable to `S`?  etc. etc.), but this should at least give some direction.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHAptA3tALtAvNARLPtAL7QCwAUKJDAKIAemyAdgCbJsIoCM0yTVmxjdUGZJj558xElRpRojZu06iATP0HsRSMf0ybpsqgEsWzAE4AzMMFQb0WPeoBc0FgFcAtgCNklgDcpFSYetAAIsjIiACyYIgAPLAANNAAymkRAHy4TgDaANLQ5tAA1sjwAPbWcAC67rBFdVoqwhnQAPyR0O5RMfFJTYV1aZmRuXKU8uCKsfAAwrMQya1CMFW+AFbIwJi5aFTQ0N4JKGwAhH3RcQnJaaL5o3Au2cEA9O-Q1Z4A5GzQfyYKwlbyIEDIbysbCYAAWpggR2gwCqLAgmEsnj2VUsAAoqohMKZURB3Bg2GBMGBGqQAJROKZTeQkmHIdF5FjIADu0HmS1ouMOlGOFKpZKRx2Y6PFwuOcuAsN2ZXc+U5POUQjUeh4uNpdQlpBSBqlhhlcvliuAyugqu5Sm0HC4Ll1+tlxym7qoJFpgSooTZmAAdKdEOdAybAwqlR93hogA)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Works perfectly and I was able to adapt it as I needed. I would say that my approach was getting there, but I overcomplicated it and I wound up leading myself astray. Good explanation as well :)